Card animations and transitions
import Section from '@/components/section'
import {Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardFooter, Divider, Link, Image, Button} from "@nextui-org/react";
import { CSSProperties, useState } from 'react';
 
const Index = () => {
  const ExpandedCard = ({ card }: { card: { name: string; price: string } }) => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '30vh',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          padding: '20px',
          borderRadius: '10px',
          boxShadow: '0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
          transition: 'opacity 0.5s ease-in-out', // Add transition effect
        }}
      >
        <h2>{card.name}</h2>
        <p>{card.price} RSD</p>
        <button onClick={() => setExpandedCard(null)}>Close</button>
      </div>
    );
  };
 
  const [expandedCard, setExpandedCard] = useState<number | null>(null);
 
  const handleCardClick = (index: number) => {
    setExpandedCard(index);
  };
 
  const cards = [
    { name: 'Tost', price: '140' },
    { name: 'Sendvic', price: '150' },
    { name: 'Sendvic', price: '150' },
    { name: 'Sendvic', price: '150' },
    { name: 'Sendvic', price: '150' },
    { name: 'Sendvic', price: '150' },
    { name: 'Sendvic', price: '150' },
    { name: 'Sendvic', price: '150' },
  ];
 
  return (
    <Page>
      <Section>
        {expandedCard !== null ? (
          <ExpandedCard card={cards[expandedCard]} />
        ) : (
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 justify-center">
            {cards.map((card: { name: string; price: string }, index: number) => (
              <Card
                key={index}
                isPressable
                onClick={() => handleCardClick(index)}
                style={{
                  transition: 'opacity 0.5s ease-in-out', // Add transition effect
                }}
              >
                <CardBody>
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
                  <div style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                  }}>
                    <h5>{card.name}</h5>
                    <p>{card.price} RSD</p>
                  </div>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </Section>
    </Page>
  );
};
 
export default Index
 

My animations on my NextJS project are not working for some reason, im a newbie so i dont really know whats going on.
Im using NextUI for the UI elements if that helps
The cards just appear and dissapear.
Card animations are there but they dont do anything, i think its because expanded card and the clicked cards are not the same thing so css cant animate separate elements?

I'm no react expert, but from a css point of view, this can't work. Your browser cannot transition between your two cards because he doesn't know how:
Here you are displaying a card, and if it should be expanded you display another expanded card. However, for a transition to work, the transition must be applied from a state A to a state B of the SAME element. Therefore I can only advice you to review what you are trying to do. How should the image appear ? From the left ? From opacity ?
First of all you should start by creating two CSS classes representing state A and B of the card, then you can transition the properties you need. Be aware that you can't transition computed properties. in this case, you won't be able to transition the height of the card if you don't clearly specify height value for both states.
I hope this helps you, lmk if you need more help
